# async/await not working with promise chaining

Tags: typescript, async-await, protractor

My code looks like this:

```
await enterName();
await enterCity();
await submit();

async enterName() {
element.sendKeys('name');
}
async submit() {
element.submit();
waitForAngular();
}
```

The issue here is when calling submit function(async), it's not able to make any network call at all.
I tried with controlFlow but it seems it only works if I get the url right before submit.
       `protractor.promise.controlFlow.execute( driver.get(url));
        await submit();` ----------> works!

However my requirement is to open this url first, fill up the form and then make the async submit call. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to await ALL functions that return promises, including those from protractor:

```
class x {
    element = element(".test");
    async enterName() {
        await this.element.sendKeys('name');
    }

    async enterCity() {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }

    async waitForAngular() {
        return Promise.resolve();
    }
    async submit() {
        await this.element.submit();
        await this.waitForAngular();  // Assuming this is async as well.
    }

    async test() {
        await this.enterName();
        await this.enterCity();
        await this.submit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. For working with `async/await` you MUST [disable Control Flow](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/control-flow.md) .
2. Function should be `async` only if inside you should handle some promise using `await`.